Class works with SuperClass.__init__() but not with super().__init__()
I have the class structure below. Just ignore the minor issues such as mismatching variable names, this is not the issue here, I'll explain what is in a moment.
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d=0, e=0, f=0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, b, d, **kwargs)
        # A.__init__(self, a, b, d, **kwargs)
        self.c = c


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, b, d, **kwargs)
        # A.__init__(self, a, b, d, **kwargs)
        self.c = c


class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, b, c, e, **kwargs)
        # B.__init__(self, a, b, c, e, **kwargs)
        C.__init__(self, a, b, d, e)


class E(D):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e=0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, b, c, d, e, **kwargs)
        # D.__init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    E(None, None, None, 0)

When I run this code, it gives the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 39, in <module>
    E(None, None, None, 0)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 34, in __init__
    super().__init__(a, b, c, d, e, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 27, in __init__
    super().__init__(a, b, c, e, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(a, b, d, **kwargs)
TypeError: C.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

However, if I replace each of the super().__init__() calls with the first superclass.__init__ (which is apparently not the same thing or otherwise both cases should fail), it works perfectly fine.
To make it work, just uncomment all super().__init__() calls and uncomment all commented lines, it will work perfectly fine. The question is why both cases don't fail? and how does super().__init__ work differently? doesn't super() resolve to the first superclass? is the simplified logic below wrong?
class A(B, C)
    def __init__():
         super().__init__()  # is this not equivalent to B.__init__()?


I suggest reading https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/. Cooperative multiple inheritance doesn't work well with positional arguments.

There may be some useful info on how super behaves with multiple inheritance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance and here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-multiple-inheritance-with-super-function/

Note that your modification does not work "perfectly fine". You end up calling A.__init__ twice, once before C.__init__ and once after.

Python super is funky; it finds the next class in the method resolution order (MRO) of type(self), not the first "superclass" as you mean it.
When you call super().__init__ in B.__init__, super looks for the next class in the MRO of self, which is of type E. If you look at E.__mro__, it's something like:
(<class '__main__.E'>, <class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
The class after B here is C, so C.__init__ is called.
This is documented in the official Python docs for super.
To answer your edit: the simplified logic is correct. However, the way Python looks up super().__init__ inside B.__init__ is not the way you might have expected.

When you are instantiating E, the following chain of inheritance occurs:
E -> D -> B -> C -> A

This is called the method resolution order (MRO).  What you will notice is that this is different than the MRO for the class B, which is just:
B -> A

without class C in between.  The addition of C to the MRO is because of the multiple inheritance.  This means that when instantiating E, the call to super() within the class B references class C and NOT class A.
This is because the self that gets passed in to each super().__init__ is from the original instantiating class, in this case E.
Here is an example to show the MRO:
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print('A:', [c.__name__ for c in self.__class__.mro()])
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print('B:', [c.__name__ for c in self.__class__.mro()])
        super().__init__(a)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print('C:', [c.__name__ for c in self.__class__.mro()])
        super().__init__(a)

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print('D:', [c.__name__ for c in self.__class__.mro()])
        super().__init__(a)

class E(D):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print('E:', [c.__name__ for c in self.__class__.mro()])
        super().__init__(a)

E(0)
# prints:
# E: ['E', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'object']
# D: ['E', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'object']
# B: ['E', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'object']
# C: ['E', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'object']
# A: ['E', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'object']

The MRO does not change through the entire super stack.  When each class calls super(), if finds itself in the MRO, and then returns a reference to the next object in the MRO chain.  This is why the behavior of super() in B is different when instantiating E versus instantiating B directly.
Here is what B creates:
B(0)
# prints:
# B: ['B', 'A', 'object']
# A: ['B', 'A', 'object']

How to fix it?
In order for D to inherit from both B and C, then C would need to have the same init parameters as A.
If you really need your inputs for A and C to be different, you can check the MRO in B and modify the parameters on the fly.  Keep in mind, this greatly increases how tightly coupled your code is, and is very hard to maintain.
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
        mro = self.__class__.mro()
        ix = mro.index(B)
        if mro[ix+1] == A:
            super().__init__(a, b, d, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(a, b, c, d, **kwargs)
        self.c = c

